# Correct Query wrong output

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have this query in my project

```
u_name = Application.Current.Properties["username"].ToString();
cmd = new SqlCommand("Select 'User ID' = u_id, 'USERNAME' = u_name, 'ROLE' = r_name from [User] as u, [Role] as r Where u_name != '@u_name' and u.r_id = r.r_id and r_name like '%" + txtBoxSearch.Text.Replace("'", "''").Trim() + "%' or u_name like '%" + txtBoxSearch.Text.Replace("'", "''").Trim() + "%'", conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@u_name", u_name);

da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

dt = new DataTable("User");
da.Fill(dt);
dataGridUser.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
dataGridUser.Columns[0].Visibility = System.Windows
                                  .Visibility
                                  .Hidden;
```

When I try to use the query in SQL Server, It shows the correct output but when I use it in my project and show it in a datagrid using search button. It still shows the username that should not be shown because of  **u_name != @u_name** statement I use in my query.Whats wrong with that?

Comment: You have single quotes around strings in a context where they will be interpreted as constants.  Your query is wrong.

Comment: I believe that this syntax still works in most version of SQL Server, but has been deprecated for some time and is slated for removal soon.  So you should change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because of your final OR clause. You have this at the end of your query:

```
    or u_name like '%" + txtBoxSearch.Text.Replace("'", "''").Trim() + "%'
```

Use ( and ) to enclose different groups of your WHERE clause for the correct result. You are perhaps getting the right output in the query analyzer because you are replacing the reference to the txtBoxSearch control with a literal value.

Comment: Can you give me a sample?

Comment: your original query would become like this: 

        WHERE ( (u_name != '@u_name') and (u.r_id = r.r_id) and (r_name like '%" + txtBoxSearch.Text.Replace("'", "''").Trim() + "%') or (u_name like '%" + txtBoxSearch.Text.Replace("'", "''").Trim() + "%') )

What you need to do is move the final " or (u_name like ..." to live along side the u_name != @u_name and enclose them in another set of ( and ).

Comment: Yup. I've come up with that can of query. Thanks for helping.

Comment: (ran out of space in previous comment). Like this --- 

 WHERE ( ((u_name != '@u_name') OR (u_name like '%" + ... "%')) or ...

Answer (score 1):

Your username is not wrapped in single quotes and is therefore being displayed as if:

```
u_name != Administrator
```

instead of

```
u_name != 'Administrator'
```

To resolve this, I suggest that you change:

```
u_name != @u_name
```

into

```
u_name != '@u_name'
```